# Cordova AppRate plugin "Rate it now" button not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, app-store, cordova-plugins

I have added AppRate plugin into my project and it shows popup when I want it to see, but when I press button "Rate it now" I see this error "Your request produced an error. [newNullResponce]".

It happens only on iOS, on Android everything is ok.

I use theses preferences:

```
App.config.storeAppURL.ios = JKWG4X7SZ1.uk.co.domain.projectname;

AppRate.preferences.launchApp = true;
AppRate.preferences.openStoreInApp = false;
AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.ios = App.config.storeAppURL.ios;
AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.android = 'market://details?id='+App.config.storeAppURL.android;
AppRate.preferences.usesUntilPrompt = 2;
AppRate.preferences.promptAgainForEachNewVersion = false;
AppRate.preferences.useCustomRateDialog = false;
AppRate.preferences.callbacks.onButtonClicked = onButtonClicked;
```

Does anybody know why it may happens?

Comment: You should use App id not package name for iOS.

Comment: Same for me. I am setting it up with the id but keep getting `[newNullResponse]`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the App ID inside quotes worked for me.[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/ to find out app id for iOS.

For example:
You find id of App from this link and use it below...

https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/d-risk-it/id983515981?mt=8

AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.ios = '**983515981**';